# Временное отключение Unique constraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Имеется модель задачи:

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    index = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Нумерация')
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(..., verbose_name='Раздел')
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('chapter', 'index')
        verbose_name_plural = 'Задачи'
        verbose_name = 'Задача'
```

Каждая задача привязана к разделу. Задачи имеют уникальную порядковую нумерацию в рамках раздела.

Мне необходимо реализовать функцию изменения порядка задач, в UI это выглядит как перетаскивание задач путем нажатия на стрелочки вверх/вниз. На сервер приходит json вида:

```json
{
  *task_id1*: *order_delta1*,
  *task_id2*: *order_delta2*,
}
```

`task_id` - id задачи
`order_delta` - дельта, на которую поменялась нумерация задачи

И дальше я написал вот такую функцию:

```py
def save_order_changes(changes: list[ChangeEntry]):
    changed_ids = (change.task_id for change in changes)
    # Создаем условия
    statements = (
        When(pk=change.task_id, then=F('index') + change.delta)
        for change in changes
    )
    # Создаем условия
    Task.objects.filter(pk__in=changed_ids).update(
        index=Case(*statements)
    )
```

Но из-за `unique_together` я получаю ошибку:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: tasks_task.chapter_id, tasks_task.index
```

Мне казалось, что в рамках одного запроса проверка падать не должна, ведь значения в конечном виде должны фиксироваться с соблюдением уникальности?

Есть ли варианты обхода? Можно ли временно отключить для одного запроса проверку на уникальность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некоторые СУБД поддерживают [отложенную проверку](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#deferrable) ограничений. Это конфигурируется так:

```
from django.db.models import Deferrable, UniqueConstraint

class Task(..):

  class Meta:
    contraints = [
        UniqueConstraint(
            name='unique_chapter_index',
            fields=['chapter', 'index'],
            deferrable=Deferrable.DEFERRED,
        )
    ]
```

Проверка в таком случае делается в конце транзакции. Если используется автокоммит, то в конце операции update.

Comment: В моем случае, к сожалению, такой вариант не сработает, т.к. во время разработки пока что используем SQLite, а Postgres только на тестовом стенде, но все равно огромное спасибо!

Comment: Postgres очень легко запускать локально в докере ;)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему используя фейковые временные номера, чтобы освободить изменяемые значения

Порядок действий такой:

1. Запоминаем старые номера изменяемых записей
2. Изменяемым записям проставляем фейковые номера, к примеру 30000, 30001 и т.д
3. Используя сохраненные старые номера проставляем новые валидные